# Realod page in jquery mobile after editing

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, web-applications

Hello i'm  finished an app for android using phonegap, right now i'm trying to change the code for a webapp ( the app is simply a notes save ),  But i have a problem when change pages, after a edit a  note the app goes back to the index page  and when you click on a note for view a single note, the apps goes again of the index page ( this happens once, if you click again , works fine)

DEMO
[notesapp](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/206266247/notesApp/index.html)

THis is part of js code

```
 editNote: function(e){
        var noteId = $("#id-note").attr("value");
        var newText = $.trim($("#textarea-edit").val());
        var storage = window.localStorage.getItem("notes");
        storage = JSON.parse(storage);
        var newStorage = [];


        for( obj in storage ){
            if(noteId == storage[obj].id){
                newStorage.push({
                    id: storage[obj].id,
                    text: newText,
                    created: storage[obj].created 
                });
            }else{
                newStorage.push(storage[obj])
            }
        }

        window.localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(newStorage));
        notes.showNotes();
        $.mobile.changePage($('#index'));


    }

$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e, data){
    var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage )
    if(u.hash){
        var page = u.hash.split("?")[0],
            idNote = u.hash.split("=")[1],
            storage = window.localStorage.getItem("notes"),
            singleText
        ;

        storage = JSON.parse(storage);

        // GET CURRENT NOTE TEXT
        for( obj in storage ){
            if(idNote == storage[obj].id){
                singleText = storage[obj].text;
            }
        }

        // SET ID-NOTE TO A INPUT HIDE FOR LATER RETRIEVE
        $("#id-note").attr("value", idNote)

        if(page == "#single"){ 
            if(idNote){
                console.log("show single page")  

                $("#single-note").html(singleText);
                $("#editnote-button").attr("href","#editnote?id=" + idNote);
            }
        }else if(page == "#editnote"){
            console.log("Show edit")

            $("#textarea-edit").val(singleText);
        }

    }


  });
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in `notes.init()` in `pageinit`. You add mulitple `click` events. Try for example `$("#save-note").off("click").on("click", notes.saveNote);`. or bind `pageinit` to `#index` page. `$(document).on("pageinit", "#index", function ()` This will run `init()` function once only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in executing `notes.init()` whenever a page is initiated `pageinit`. As per your code, `notes.init()` adds multiple `click` listener to the buttons below.

```
$("#save-note").on("click", notes.saveNote);
$("#delete-note").on("click", notes.deleteNote);
$("#edit-note-button").on("click", notes.editNote);
```

To solve the problem, either bind `pageinit` to `#index` page. This way `notes.init()` will run once only. Or remove old `click` binding and re-bind it to same buttons.

```
$("#save-note").off("click").on("click", notes.saveNote);
$("#delete-note").off("click").on("click", notes.deleteNote);
$("#edit-note-button").off("click").on("click", notes.editNote);
```

Or run `pageinit` one time only.

```
$(document).one("pageinit", function () {
  notes.init();
});
```